# Get files recursively from azure file storage using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage-files

I want to write a program to fetch the files from azure file storage but the problem is depth of directories is not defined and `isFile` property of file always returns false.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure; // Namespace for Azure Configuration Manager
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; // Namespace for Storage Client Library
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob; // Namespace for Blob storage
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File; // Namespace for File storage

namespace AzureStorage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            //CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            // Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to File storage.
            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            // Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("my-FileShare");

            // Ensure that the share exists.
            if (share.Exists())
            {
                // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();


                // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
                CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("FILES");

                // Ensure that the directory exists.
                if (sampleDir.Exists())
                {
                    var directoryLists = sampleDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                    //sampleDir.ge
                    foreach (var yearDirTemp in directoryLists)
                    {
                        var yearDir = sampleDir.GetDirectoryReference(
                                        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(yearDirTemp.Uri.LocalPath)
                                        );
                        foreach (var monthDirTemp in yearDir.ListFilesAndDirectories())
                        {
                            var monthDir = yearDir.GetDirectoryReference(
                                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(monthDirTemp.Uri.LocalPath)
                                            );
                            foreach (var patientDirTemp in monthDir.ListFilesAndDirectories())
                            {
                                var patientDir = monthDir.GetDirectoryReference(
                                                   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(patientDirTemp.Uri.LocalPath)
                                                   );
                                foreach (var patientDataTemp in patientDir.ListFilesAndDirectories())
                                {
                                    var patientData = patientDir.GetDirectoryReference(
                                                   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(patientDataTemp.Uri.LocalPath)
                                                   );

                                   var fileList = patientData.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                                    foreach(var fileTemp in fileList)
                                    {
                                        // Here fileTemp could be file 
                                        // or directory containing more child directories
                                        var file1 = patientData.GetFileReference(Path.GetFileName(fileTemp.Uri.LocalPath));
                                        file1.FetchAttributes();
                                        byte[] arrTarget = new byte[file1.Properties.Length];
                                        file1.DownloadToByteArray(arrTarget, 0);                                        
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 7):

```
    public static void list_file()
    {
        //***** Get list of all files/directories on the file share*****//
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
        CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("dummyfile");

        // List all files/directories under the root directory.
        Console.WriteLine("Getting list of all files/directories under the root directory of the share.");

        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories();

        // Print all files/directories listed above.
        foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
        {
            // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory.
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.GetType());
            if(listItem.GetType()== typeof(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory))
            {

                list_subdir(listItem);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void list_subdir(IListFileItem list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("subdir");
        CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory=(CloudFileDirectory)list;
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories();


        // Print all files/directories in the folder.
        foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
        {
            // listItem type will be CloudFile or CloudFileDirectory.
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this program, directory and its corresponding sub folders are displayed.

Comment: The Execution of the above program will be:                                                                                           Getting list of all files/directories under the root directory of the share.
dir
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory
subdir
file%201.txt
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFile
mydir
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory
subdir
note.txt
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I get a compile error : 'IListFileItem' does not conain a defenition for 'DownloadToFile' and no extention method 'DownloadToFile' accepting a first argument of type 'IListFileItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) when I try the download to file line , any ideas to why is that ?

Comment: This program lists files only upto level 2 hierarchy. Maybe the same if statement in the list_dir() can help.

Answer (score 3):

> depth of directories is not defined and isFile property of file always returns false.

If you want to do some actions when the fileTemp is File, please try with following code. We can use GetType method to get its type, then use name property to get its type value. If the value is "CloudFile", then we do some actions, such as download and so on.

```html
 foreach (var fileTemp in fileList)
 {
     // Here fileTemp could be file 
     // or directory containing more child directories
     switch (fileTemp.GetType().Name)
     {
         case "CloudFile":
             var file1 = patientData.GetFileReference(Path.GetFileName(fileTemp.Uri.LocalPath));
             file1.FetchAttributes();
             byte[] arrTarget = new byte[file1.Properties.Length];
             file1.DownloadToByteArray(arrTarget, 0);
             break;
         case "CloudFileDirectory":
             break;
     }

 }
```