# Searching for a specific file inside Azure File Storage

Tags: c#, azure, file-storage

I have some performance issues while trying to get specific files from Azure Storage.
We have the following folder tree inside Azure:
[image]

In the folder Week there is a file. I would like to get on one call precise file based on Location, Year and Week. Currently there is a working solution but it isn't efficient. It is looking recursively  through folder tree.
Does anyone has a better solution ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520442/get-files-recursively-from-azure-file-storage-using-c-sharp went through this link ?

Comment: Please share your code.